# Is there any differences between create object and then return it or create and return it directly?

Tags: c#, .net

Sorry for the title, it's hard to tell. Please look at my example.
Is there any differences between GetUser1 and GetUser2 ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetUser1();
        GetUser2();
    }

    private static User GetUser1()
    {
        return new User
    {
            Name = "Hello"
    };
    }

    private static User GetUser2()
    {
        User user = new User
        {
            Name = "Hello"
        };
        return user;
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A friend mine is saying; There is no difference.
But I'm saying that; There is a difference between two methods. GetUser2 is creating a new object which is unnecessary. And GetUser2 has minor( very minor ) performance error because you are creating a new object... What is the truth of that? How can I research this topic?

**UPDATE**
Thank you very much for answers... So I'm continue to asking;
If there is no difference between GetUser1 and GetUser2, why roslyn compiling the code ( [link](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3YBfbPJltKNOgAUATnygaq6JdPZGYKKsm78hoqpDEoNkKAG0AujCoaoICQaMtjATAA4qjIAKogqBoAjJI4voEh4ZEaAExxCWyKgRwOPGaoJshm3BFRwaFlMZKZhjnsGqHAGhAwEKgA7jBVtfVs/n2DMAByeoUAvDAARAASqEREfFO9fbI4OdmBuHkFRSXkVRXJUek+OQN9h6Dlk+1dPUNDF49Do+gT03MLSysva9i/GCNZDNVrXDTrQLyIybNicEjkFS0bopAzPIzw7j2RwjMbMGBQUKYExEmDQuRAA==) ) like this;

```
private static User GetUser1()
{
    return new User {
        Name = "Hello"
    };
}
```

Comment: No, there's no difference.  GetUser1 is just a more concise version of GetUser2.

Comment: no there is no diffrence Because You create a new instance with in both method

Comment: In fact, I bet the CIL is the same for both.

Comment: "performance error because you are creating a new object" <- there is a `new` in both, so why do you think only one "creates a new object"? Are you talking about the local variable `user`?

Comment: No difference with class allocations, `GetUser2` will be easier to debug since you can add a breakpoint on the return statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference when compiled in *Release mode*. If you view the emitted IL in *Debug mode*, you'll notice a subtle difference in the form of an additional [`stloc/ldloc` instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) for storing and loading the variable before returning the object.

If you look at [the generated compiler code](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3YBfbPJltKNOgAUATnygaq6JdPZGYKKsm78hoqpDEoNkKAG0AujCoaoICQaMtjATAA4qjIAKogqBoAjJI4voEh4ZEaAExxCWyKgRwOPGaoJshm3BFRwaFlMZKZhjnsGqHAGhAwEKgA7jBVtfVs/n2DMAByeoUAvDAARAASqEREfFO9fbI4OdmBuHkFRSXkVRXJUek+OQN9h6Dlk+1dPUNDF49Do+gT03MLSysva9i/GCNZDNVrXDTrQLyIybNicEjkFS0bopAzPIzw7j2RwjMbMGBQUKYExEmDQuRAA==), you'll get two identical results:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program.GetUser1();
    Program.GetUser2();
}
private static User GetUser1()
{
    return new User {
        Name = "Hello"
    };
}
private static User GetUser2()
{
    return new User {
        Name = "Hello"
    };
}
```

And [the generated IL code](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:%3Eilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3YBfbPJltKNOgAUATnygaq6JdPZGYKKsm78hoqpDEoNkKAG0AujCoaoICQaMtjATAA4qjIAKogqBoAjJI4voEh4ZEaAExxCWyKgRwOPGaoJshm3BFRwaFlMZKZhjnsGqHAGhAwEKgA7jBVtfVs/n2DMAByeoUAvDAARAASqEREfFO9fbI4OdmBuHkFRSXkVRXJUek+OQN9h6Dlk+1dPUNDF49Do+gT03MLSysva9i/GCNZDNVrXDTrQLyIybNicEjkFS0bopAzPIzw7j2RwjMbMGBQUKYExEmDQuRAA==) for both:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    class User GetUser1 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2068
    // Code size 17 (0x11)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: newobj instance void User::.ctor()
    IL_0005: dup
    IL_0006: ldstr "Hello"
    IL_000b: callvirt instance void User::set_Name(string)
    IL_0010: ret
} // end of method Program::GetUser1

.method private hidebysig static 
    class User GetUser2 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2068
    // Code size 17 (0x11)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: newobj instance void User::.ctor()
    IL_0005: dup
    IL_0006: ldstr "Hello"
    IL_000b: callvirt instance void User::set_Name(string)
    IL_0010: ret
} // end of method Program::GetUser2
```

Comment: Guys, sorry for the question that can seem stupid. What does IL stand for? Thanx

Comment: @user449689 It (MSIL/CIL) stand for [Microsoft Intermediate Language/Common Intermediate Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)

Comment: Your code is identical in both cases. I assume that's a cut and past error?

Comment: @ChrisF No, that's the actual C# code that's generated in Release mode. TryRoslyn emits IL back to C# code.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov sir, can you answer my updated question please ? If two methods are the same, why roslyn converting GetUser2 method to GetUser1 ?

Comment: @Lost_In_Library Because that is what the compiler actually emits. The CIL emitted by the compiler with **optimization turned on** will remove the unnecessary `stloc/ldloc` commands and simply return the object which is already on the evaluation stack.

Answer (score 5):

There's a tiny difference in debug builds without jitter optimisation, because the redundancy isn't removed so you can more easily examine the value in a debugger.

A release build will remove it, and jitter optimisation could do so too, so outside of debugging situations the two are the same.

Answer (score 2):

> There is a difference between two methods. GetUser2 is creating a new object which is unnecessary. And GetUser2 has minor( very minor ) performance error because you are creating a new object.

*Both* methods are creating a new object. The method that uses an intermediate variable (`User user`) adds just that: a *variable*, which is just a pointer to the same object.

As soon as the method goes out of scope, the variable does not exist anymore.

Even in debug mode, the difference of one more variable on the stack is absolutely negligible.